# Month selector issue in Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When editing an experience's Time Frame I get few issues:

1.In the Month drop down list, 'January' is not there. This is the generated markup

```
<select class="date" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StartMonth must be a number." id="StartMonth" name="StartMonth"><option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">February</option>
<option value="2">March</option>
<option value="3">April</option>
<option value="4">May</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">June</option>
<option value="6">July</option>
<option value="7">August</option>
<option value="8">September</option>
<option value="9">October</option>
<option value="10">November</option>
<option value="11">December</option>
<option value="12"></option>
</select>
```

2.If I select, "June" here, in the profile page it shows "May" that is just one month earlier than what I've actually selected.

i've taken the screenshots. please let me know if submitting those will help.

Comment: Someone started the for loop at 1 instead of 0... *rolls eyes*

Comment: then, where is January? it should not be omitted. it could be set for 0.

Comment: The array is likely `[ 0 => January, 1 => February, 2 => March, ... ]`. If you start the loop at 1 instead of 0, and go 12 spaces, you'll start at February, go through December, and then get a warning for trying to access element [12] which doesn't exist, which oddly looks like what's happening here. Note the *actual* value 0 at the top is used for the "not specified" option.

Comment: The [list of month names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx) has 13 values, and a recent refactor assumed the extra was at the front instead of the end.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed. Thanks for the report.

Comment: i wanted to test it. when i hit 'save' after updating month, i'm redirected to this url 'http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/updatesection/97929?sectionId=340733' and I am getting json response. Why?

Comment: What browser/version are you using? Is javascript enabled?

Comment: Chrome 23x. Yes, it is enabled.