# January is missing from the dropdown when adding jobs to my profile

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Month selector issue in the Career 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155315/month-selector-issue-in-the-career-2)

When adding an Experience, the month of January is absent from the dropdown.

When an Experience is posted, it's begin and end date will be 1 month before what was selected.

Comment: Yep, this is the right place.